# Axiom of Regularity applied to the form $A=\{\{A, B\}, C\}$, not the usual $A=\{A,B\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Axiom of Regularity tells us the following is disallowed:

$$ A = \{ A, B \} $$

where A and B are either sets, or fundamental objects ("lowest hierarchy" as described by Terence Tao's Analysis I). Clearly, here $A$ is a set.

---

Now, as I was doing an exercise I came to a point in the proof resulting in the following two statements:

$$a = \{x, y\}$$
$$x = \{a, b\}$$

Here we have the following form, which is different to the above used to illustrate the Axion of Regularity:

$$ A = \{\{A, B\}, C\} $$

Intuitively, this cannot be true, because this is a recursive definition of an infinitely deep set.

**Question:** Does the Axiom of Regularity still apply? If so, how can I apply it to the form $A = \{\{A, B\}, C\}$ when it is traditionally applied to the form $A=\{A, B\}$.

**Request:** I am self-teaching and a beginner in this subject. It is likely I have not fully understood the axiom of regularity, so gentle guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I would say the text is in error.  Is there more to the context?  Were the sets "solid" or were they more hypothetical constructs.

Answer (score 2):

The axiom of regularity implies there is no infinite descending sequence of sets. This is [explained on the Axiom of Regularity Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists), but I'll give a simpler explanation applied to your scenario of $A=\{\{A,B\},C\}$. To do this, we won't apply axiom of regularity to $A$ directly, but we will apply axiom of regularity to a set constructed from $A$.

Suppose, for purpose of contradiction, there exists sets $A,B,C$ such that $A=\{\{A,B\},C\}$. Then, we can construct a set $S=\{A,\{A,B\}\}$. However, notice that:

- $A$ is not disjoint from $S$, because $\{A,B\}\in A$ and $\{A,B\}\in S$
- $\{A,B\}$ is not disjoint from $S$, because $A\in \{A,B\}$ and $A\in S$

Therefore, all elements in $S$ are not disjoint from $S$, which contradicts the axiom of regularity. Thus, by contradiction, there exists no sets $A,B,C$ such that $A=\{\{A,B\},C\}$.

Comment: Thanks Noble, I will print this out and ponder on it today, hopefully I will understand it. As I do .. can I ask, is your answer equivalent to the implication of the axion of regularity that: given two sets $A$ and $B$, then $A \notin B$ or $B \notin A$, or both?